# SQL Query to find the number of rows with a common field

Tags: sql-server

In MS SQL Server 2008.
How do I count the number of rows that have a certain field in common.
Example, lets say I have the following table.

```
UserAccount_ID Attribute_ID
786            11
797            10
797            5
797            6
797            11
555            11
1003           10
1003           5
1003           6
1003           11
633            11
2036           11
2087           10
2087           5
2087           6
291            11
```

What query do I need to perform to get the following table. This will count the number of records with the same UserAccount_ID

```
UserAccount_ID Count
    786            1
    797            4
    555            1
    1003            4
    633            1
    2036            1
    2087            3
    291              1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table #YourTable (
    UserAccount_ID int,
    Attribute_ID int
)

insert into #YourTable
    (UserAccount_ID, Attribute_ID)
    select 786,11 union all
    select 797,10 union all
    select 797,5 union all
    select 797,6 union all
    select 797,11 union all
    select 555,11 union all
    select 1003,10 union all
    select 1003,5 union all
    select 1003,6 union all
    select 1003,11 union all
    select 633,11 union all
    select 2036,11 union all
    select 2087,10 union all
    select 2087,5 union all
    select 2087,6 union all
    select 291,11

select UserAccount_ID, count(*)
    from #YourTable
    group by UserAccount_ID

drop table #YourTable
```

Comment: This seems right but when I tried it, it gave me two columns. One with the UserAcount_ID and the other column of Count with every entry as 4.

Comment: @bhavinp: Not sure why that would happen. I've added your sample data to my answer to illustrate that the technique works.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple aggregate query. "COUNT per UserAccount_ID grouping"

```
SELECT
   UserAccount_ID, COUNT(*)
FROm
   myTable
GROUP BY
   UserAccount_ID
```